# Prove Matrix logarithm and exponential are inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do we show that the exponential function is the inverse of the logarithm function in the case for matrices, since they are defined as series.

I.e. Defining $\ln(I+A) = A-A^2/2+\cdots$ and $\exp(A) = I + A + A^2/2! +\cdots$. We want to show $\exp(\ln(I+A))=I+A$. For the $\ln(I+A)$ to be defined we must have that $A$ is of norm less than 1. I assume this restriction does not go away when taking exponential.